# Magento /shell folder permissions?

Tags: magento-1.7

What are /shell folder permissions for Magento 1.x? Are they 755 or 644?

In any case, if you open /shell folder and try to click on any of the files the all show the message **"This script cannot be run from Browser. This is the shell script."**
I assume it doesnt really matter what permissions are, 700 is fine. Correct if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Magento recomended 500 for shell folder.

```
  find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \;
  find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \; 
  find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \; 
  find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
  find var/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \; 
  find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
  chmod 700 includes
  chmod 600 includes/config.php
```

you can find more information about permision on offical installation guide: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

Answer (score 0):

In general **all files** should be **644** and **all folders** should be **755** and should be owned by the user your web server runs under. The **Mage executable** should be given **550** permissions to allow execution.

This shell script should patch things up if run from your Mage root:

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod 550 mage
```